# How to retrieve values from dynamically created textboxes in VB?

Tags: vb.net

May i ask how to retrieve values from dynamically created textboxes?

Here's how my program should work.

The program will ask the user how many textboxes should be created. Upon creation, user will input values to these textboxes (burst time textboxes). Then, when a button is clicked, values will be fetched from these textboxes and these will be used to compute for the waiting time and turnaround time which will be displayed in the textboxes waiting time and turnaround time textboxes respectively.

I am working with First Come First Serve Algorithm. Please help me.

This is my code:
Public Class Form6

```
Private Sub Form6_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Public Sub Process_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'creates burst time textboxes

    GroupBox3.Visible = True
    Button1.Visible = True
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim burstbox(15) As TextBox
    For cnt = 0 To Val(TextBox1.Text) - 1

        burstbox(cnt) = New TextBox
        With burstbox(cnt)
            .Parent = Me
            .Left = 0
            .Height = 13
            .Width = 80
            .Top = .Height * cnt + 50
            .Visible = True
            .Tag = cnt
            .Text = ""
            .Name = "burst" & cnt
            .Location = New Point(90, 170 + (cnt * 25))

        End With
    Next cnt

    'creates waiting time textboxes
    Dim cnt2 As Integer
    Dim waitbox(15) As TextBox
    For cnt2 = 0 To Val(TextBox1.Text) - 1

        waitbox(cnt2) = New TextBox
        With waitbox(cnt2)
            .Parent = Me
            .Left = 0
            .Height = 13
            .Width = 80
            .Top = .Height * cnt2 + 50
            .Visible = True
            .Tag = cnt2
            .Text = ""
            .Name = "wait" & cnt2
            .Location = New Point(200, 170 + (cnt2 * 25))
            .ReadOnly = True
        End With
    Next cnt2

    'creates turnaround time textboxes
    Dim cnt3 As Integer
    Dim turnaroundbox(15) As TextBox
    For cnt3 = 0 To Val(TextBox1.Text) - 1

        turnaroundbox(cnt3) = New TextBox
        With turnaroundbox(cnt3)
            .Parent = Me
            .Left = 0
            .Height = 13
            .Width = 80
            .Top = .Height * cnt3 + 50
            .Visible = True
            .Tag = cnt3
            .Text = ""
            .Name = "turn" & cnt3
            .Location = New Point(310, 170 + (cnt3 * 25))
            .ReadOnly = True
        End With
    Next cnt3

    'process labels here
    Dim cnt4 As Integer
    Dim processlabel(15) As Label
    For cnt4 = 0 To Val(TextBox1.Text) - 1

        processlabel(cnt4) = New Label
        With processlabel(cnt4)
            .Parent = Me
            .Left = 0
            .Height = 13
            .Width = 80
            .Top = .Height * cnt4 + 50
            .Visible = True
            .Tag = cnt4
            .Text = "P" & cnt4 + 1
            .Name = "label" & cnt4
            .Location = New Point(30, 170 + (cnt4 * 25))
            .ForeColor = Color.DodgerBlue

        End With
    Next cnt4

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: using textboxname for retrive value

Comment: Instead of `Dim burstbox(15) As TextBox`, try `Private burstbox() As TextBox` outside the Process method. If you do this for each textbox array, you'll be able to access them from other methods.

Comment: How? please explain further. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create these controls and assign them to local arrays, you will only be able to access them (later) via form.controls.  It might be better to store them in a modular (form-level global) variable.  Try this code instead:

```
Private burstbox As New List(of TextBox)

Public Sub Process_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
   'creates burst time textboxes

   GroupBox3.Visible = True
   Button1.Visible = True
   Dim cnt As Integer
   For cnt = 0 To Val(TextBox1.Text) - 1

       burstbox.add(New TextBox)
       With burstbox(cnt)
          .Parent = Me
          .Left = 0
          .Height = 13
          .Width = 80
          .Top = .Height * cnt + 50
          .Visible = True
          .Tag = cnt
          .Text = ""
          .Name = "burst" & cnt
          .Location = New Point(90, 170 + (cnt * 25))
       End With
   Next cnt

  'etc
```

End Sub

Comment: Sir! one more thing.  now that i can access the values to textboxes, i'm having a hard time how to assign values to other textboxes.  Basically, the code should work like this:  BurstTime P1: 1  P2: 2  P3: 3 P4: 4  P5:  5  ||  WaitingTime:  P1: 0  P2:  1  P3:  3  P4:  6  P5:  10..  waiting time(P1) should start at 0 and the next will be waitingtime(P2)= waitingtime(P1)+burstime(P1).. and so on.  Please help me Sir.